# User input in subform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get values back from a form.
I have been trying this: [How to return a value from a Form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/c-sharp-return-value-from-form)

It does not work for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong but at the second part.

```
using (var form = new frmImportContact())
{
    var result = form.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string val = form.ReturnValue1;            //ReturnValue1 is not an option...
        string dateString = form.ReturnValue2;
        //Do something here with these values

        //for example
        this.txtSomething.Text = val;
    }
}
```

I am unable to get "ReturnValue1" to show up.  It is declared public, what else do I need to do?

Here is what I have written.  My sub-form:

```
namespace ASPE.GUI.SensorWizard
{
    public partial class PortsSensitivity : Form
    {
        public int ReturnValue1 { get; set; }
        public PortsSensitivity()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PortsBox_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, KeyPressEventArgs m)
        {
            this.ReturnValue1 = Convert.ToInt16(PortsBox.Value);
        }

        private void PortsSensitivity_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

And my main form:

```
            //Show Form (Number of Ports, Sensitivity)
            Form Part3 = new ASPE.GUI.SensorWizard.PortsSensitivity();
            DialogResult dr3 = new DialogResult();
            dr3 = Part3.ShowDialog();
            //Write Variables
            int numofports = Part3.ReturnValue1;  //Not an option.
            //Close Form
```

Comment: Change `Form Part3 = new ASPE.GUI.SensorWizard.PortsSensitivity();` to `PortSensitivity Part3 = new ASPE.GUI.SensorWizard.PortsSensitivity();`

Comment: ^ or cast to `((PortsSensitivity)Part3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Part3` variable is defined as type `Form` which does not declare the `ReturnValue1` property. (the `ReturnValue1` property is declared on your `PortSensitivity` class).

Change

```
Form Part3 = new ASPE.GUI.SensorWizard.PortsSensitivity();
```

to

```
PortSensitivity Part3 = new ASPE.GUI.SensorWizard.PortsSensitivity();
```

Your first example is also instantiating something of type `frmImportContact` in the using statement but you have not shown the implementation of this. Check you have declared the property on this type (or that you aren't meant to be creating an instance of the `PortSensitivity` type).

Comment: Okay, thanks.  However it says the namespace "PortsSensitivity" could not be found?

Comment: either change it to be `ASPE.GUI.SensorWizard.PortsSensitivity` or at the top of your class put `using ASPE.GUI.SensorWizard;`