# How to send Selected color from form2 to form1

Tags: c#, winforms, themes

I have a Form1 with MenuItem 'Customize'. On clicking customize, I open 'Form2'. On Form2 , user selects  two colors from ColorDialog. Form2 has 'Apply' button. I want on clicking 'Apply' button, Form2 should close(or Hide) and the chosen colors should be applied (painted) as backround color of Form1. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In form 2 you need to have two properties that you can access to retrieve the colours

```
public Color FirstColor {get; private set;}
public Color SecondColor {get; private set;}
```

Then to open this form you should use something along the following.

```
using(var myForm = new Form2())
{
    myForm.ShowDialog();
    //if(myForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        this.BackColor = myForm.FirstColor;
}
```

The commented line is an optional thing that you can introduce instead of the line above it if you have an ok/cancel button on your dialog. To close the form you should set the forms `DialogResult` appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You make a public method "selectcolor()" in form1, close all forms, open a new form1 and use the selectcolor() to pick the color

Comment: I don't want to select color in form1. I want to select color in form2 and apply it to form1.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button to open form 2 do it like this:

```
 Form2 f = new Form2();
 f.ShowDialog();
 var returnedColor = f.SelectedColor;
```

This will interupt the code in form1 so you cannot make changes there, and you return the value from the form.

```
public class Form2{
  public string SelectedColor = "Test";
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Here is a quick search for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/c-sharp-return-value-from-form

Answer (score 0):

you can use static variables like this:
in Form1:

```
Public Static Color SelectedColor;
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.ShowDialog();
this.BackColor = SelectedColor;
```

in Form2:

```
if(ColoeDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResault.OK)
{
Form1.SelectedColor = ColoeDialog1.SelectedColor;
}
```