# How to set class values in an array of class

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using Visual Studio to create a Windows Forms C# project and am trying to set up an array of a type class, and have the entries in the array correspond to the constructor string for the class. I am using an array with an index of a variable, which increases each time that a new class instance is added to the array.

I am running into the problem of the index call is outside the bounds of the array. Additionally, I am not sure that my class variables are being set for each instance. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Below is my code:

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
{
    //int that will be used to alter the index of the array
    public static int acctcount = 1;
    //array of class Account
    Account[] accounts = new Account[acctcount];
    public MainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check through each element of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.Length; i++)
        {
            string stringToCheck = textBox1.Text;
            foreach(Account x in accounts)
            {
                //check to see if entered name matches any element in the array
                if (x.Name == stringToCheck)
                {
                    //set variables in another form so that we are using the class variables for only that class
                    Variables1.selectedAccount = x.Name;
                    //is this calling the CheckBalance of the instance?
                    Variables1.selectedCheckBalance = Account.CheckBalance;
                    //same thing?
                    Variables1.selectedSaveBalance = Account.SaveBalance;

                    //switch to form
                    AccountMenu acctMenu = new AccountMenu();
                    this.Hide();
                    acctMenu.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    /*insert new instance of Account
                    the index element should be 0, since acctcount is set to 1
                    and we are subtracting 1 from the acctcount
                     we are using the string from the textbox1.Text as the constructor
                     for the new instance*/
                    accounts [acctcount-1] = new Account(stringToCheck);
                    //increase the index of the array by 1
                    acctcount += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
class Account
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
    private static int acctNum = 0;
    public static int AcctNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return acctNum;
        }
        set
        {
            acctNum = value;
        }
    }
    //initialize the CheckBalance value to 100.00
    private static decimal checkBalance = 100.00M;
    public static decimal CheckBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return checkBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            checkBalance = value;
        }
    }
    public Account(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    private static decimal saveBalance = 100.00M;
    public static decimal SaveBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return saveBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            saveBalance = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you probably want the properties on the `Account` class to be instance properties not static properties...

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an array instead of a List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the reported exception is [most likely] the line `accounts[acctcount-1]` as it will throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception when `acctcount` is >= 2 (eg. `accounts[1]`), as happens after the first button click and increment of `acctcount`. The array however, *only* has one element as it was created with `accounts = new Account[acctcount];` - **arrays in C# do *not* grow/resize**.

The simplest and best immediate fix is to use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) (see [Collections (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx)) instead of an array; Lists *can* grow dynamically. Then the code becomes:

```
// (remove the "acctcount" field as it is no longer useful)
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
// ..
accounts.Add(new Account(stringToCheck));
```

---

As pointed out by Trevor, *remove* the [`static` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) in the Accounts class; otherwise the member data will be incorrectly shared (ie. each account will have the same balances!) and "overwrite" each other. If the use of static is an attempt to "pass back" the data from the form see [How to return a value from a Form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/c-sharp-return-value-from-form) for a more viable solution. The same use of a public property can be used to pass an (Account) object *into* a form.

Comment: Thanks. Switching to a list makes sense. Alternatively, couldn't array.Resize be used, instead? For the static modifier, I used that to be able to set the Variables1 properties. I understand what you are saying, though. How can I access the variables of the instance, based on the array element?

Comment: @JustinDay Arrays.Resize creates a *new* array. It uses the `ref` keyword to reassign the variable supplied as the input. I do not recommend using this approach here, although there are some use-cases for arrays.

Comment: @JustinDay As far as having access to the data, supply the *actual* Account object to modify. For example, in the form to modify the account information have a public Account property. Set this to the account to modify *before* showing the form and then modify *that object* (as assigned to the Account property of the Form) from within the form.

Comment: @JustinDay To make the code cleaner, remove the loop seen in the current Click handler and create a method called `Account FindByName(string name)`. Find the account in there, should it exist, and return it (or null if it does not).

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown when the button is clicked more than once.

You created an array of size 1, the second time you click the button and it tries to add an element at index 2, the index is already out of bounds.

Arrays do not grow in size as you add new items.

As pointed out, you should use a collection, like `List<T>`

If you wanted to keep using arrays, everytime you add a new item, you need to create a new array of bigger size, copy the elements of the old array to the new array, and reference the old array to the new array. You can also create an array of a bigger size and only create a new array when it's full. Which is basically what the .Net collections already implement.

As always, it all depends on what your needs and requirements are.