# How to open a C# windows form in another correctly by clicking a button?

Tags: c#, winforms

![enter image description here][1]I want to design a c# windows form which when user clicks a button, a new form opens and gets some values. Then I use that values in parent form.
But when I start the program and click the button, Visual Studio opens a blank win form, while I expected it opens the child form that I designed before.
So what is the reason? I can't find any solutions. What is your ideas?
Here are the codes:

---

### Form1

```
private void button1__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.Show();
        }
```

### Form2

```
        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Date_Time
{

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Label label1;
        private Label label2;
        private Label label3;
        private TextBox txtYear;
        private TextBox txtMonth;
        private Button btnOk;
        private TextBox txtDay;

        public void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtYear = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtMonth = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtDay = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.btnOk = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 9);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Change in Years: ";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 36);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.label2.Text = "Change in Months: ";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 62);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label3.Text = "Change in Days: ";
            // 
            // txtYear
            // 
            this.txtYear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(109, 6);
            this.txtYear.Name = "txtYear";
            this.txtYear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtYear.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // txtMonth
            // 
            this.txtMonth.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(109, 33);
            this.txtMonth.Name = "txtMonth";
            this.txtMonth.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtMonth.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // txtDay
            // 
            this.txtDay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(109, 59);
            this.txtDay.Name = "txtDay";
            this.txtDay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtDay.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // btnOk
            // 
            this.btnOk.ImageKey = "(none)";
            this.btnOk.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(73, 85);
            this.btnOk.Name = "btnOk";
            this.btnOk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnOk.TabIndex = 6;
            this.btnOk.Tag = "";
            this.btnOk.Text = "&Ok";
            this.btnOk.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Options
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(238, 120);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnOk);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtDay);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtMonth);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtYear);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Name = "Options";
            this.Text = "Options";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The form is *empty*, as in no controls at all? The constructor is calling `InitializeComponents`?

Comment: It is not empty Yorye. I will complete the child's form code now.

Comment: Blank means empty, as far as I'm concerned. There is a difference between designing a form and inputting values into the form (or manipulating it through code)

Comment: Your problem is either with the fact that you are opening a **new** form or your constructor doesn't call `InitializeComponent` as mentioned above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return a value from a Form in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-form-in-c) - If you want to open *the same instance* each time you click the button, you need to save a *reference* to it (and not use `new` every time)

Comment: You need to add the code for the constructor for `Form2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a glance, the thing that stands out to me is your second form is defined as so:

```
public partial class Options : Form
{
    //code
}
```

But when you try to show it to the user, you are using a `Form2` class instead of an `Options` class. Try changing your button1_Click to the following:

```
private void button1__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Options opt = new Options();
    opt.Show();
}
```

You might also want to make sure that the constructor for the `Options` form is calling the `InitializeComponent` method:

```
public partial class Options : Form
{
    public Options()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Coding for your Options' Form ok button
    }
}
```

Comment: @MojtabaShoja Does the form's constructor call the `InitializeComponent` method?

Comment: I tried it @user3189142. No response. Actually I had a mistake to copy the code here. Originally both is called Options. Sorry :))

Comment: Which form @ user3189142? Form1?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 newForm = new Form2();
   newForm.ShowDialog();

   // here you can take your parameters
   int x = newForm.x;
   int y = newForm.y;
}


// you should have definitions for x and y in your child form
public partial class Form2: Form
{
   public int x{get; set;}
   public int y{get; set;}

   public Form2(){}

   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all - "But when I start the program and click the button, Visual Studio opens a blank win form, while I expected it opens the child form that I designed before. So what is the reason?"

Comment: @Sayse OP said the form is not actually blank as in empty of controls. This is what I also understand to answer his needs. Can't really say it's an invalid answer before OP makes the question clearer.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - The only thing that seems to be clear is that the op is having a problem with opening their form, not returning values which this answer explains how to do. I agree that this question is unclear

Comment: Please take a look at this picture. Hope you undrestand my problem. :) http://oi61.tinypic.com/9hjdjk.jpg

Comment: @MojtabaShoja So it IS empty of controls, why did you say otherwise? You are either not calling `InitializeComponents` in the constructor or you are instantiating the wrong (a different, empty) form by mistake.

Comment: The absurd mistake of mine was that I didn't call `InitializeComponents` in the constructor. Anyway thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking your time friends. I found the reason finally by @user3189142's and Yorye's help. :) Thank you!

The child form(Options) was not complete. It was missing following code:

---

```
 public Options()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Thanks all.