# C# use a method on another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

On my main form in my Windows C# application I have this method:

```
        public void uploadNew(String newName, String filePath)
    {
        //Make sure file doesn't exist, then continue
        if (!File.Exists(basePath + POnumber + newName))
        {
            File.Copy(filePath, basePath + POnumber + newName);
            LogSubmit("Added New File " + newName);
            listFiles();
        }
        else
        {
            //The file already exists
                        }
    }
```

The meaning of the code really doesn't matter. Here's what I am trying to do. I needed a new form for a file upload form with some options and such. What I need is to send two variables back to the main form to plug into that method.

The operation is essentially this.

Main form -> Click button -> Form 2 -> operations -> Send back variables to uploadNew -> Close Form 2

Comment: Don't put the method in the form!  Have it in a separate class.

Comment: Instead of sending the Variables back to UploadNew why not have the variables in a seperate class aswell as the method as mentioned above and the class named to explain what the variables do and then set them when you need to send them back, from here you can use the instance of this class to get the values back.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a dialog.  Essentially, you can do something like this in the MainForm:

```
using(var form = new Form2())
{
    if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
    {
        // Newname and Filepapth are properties you set in the Form2
        uploadNew(form.NewName, form.Filepath);
    }
}
```

In the Form2, you probably will have a Ok, Cancel Button.  For the Ok Button event, you can set **this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok**.  On Cancel event, you can set it to something else.

This is from the top of my head, so some things might be off, but the concept is the same.

Also, a good idea is to move UploadFile to a new class, so you do not tie your business logic into your UI logic.

A more complete example here: [How to return a value from a Form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-form-in-c)

Comment: The dialog won't work, its a little more complicated than just that (I just wanted to simplify).

As for the class. I could, but I don't know how I would perform certain functions such as running the "listFiles" function which clears items from the main form's listbox and some other things.

Comment: @user2594008 So generally you would also move the dependent functions to that same class.  You can even make them static, if they don't require an instance.  It's generally a good idea to move your business logic out of your UI code, that makes it easier to maintain, test, and reuse.  Ex: for listFiles(), you can have your external class method return the List[] and bind it to the Listbox in your UI code.