# How to get the value from active form to another form on UserControl using delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

My Winform application has 3 form: MainForm, Form1 and Form2.
MainForm has an UserControl; when application starts, it calls MainForm, MainForm will be loaded and added Form1 onto UserControl:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 frm = new Form1() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TopLevel = false, Visible = true };
   xtraUserControl1.Controls.Add(frm);
}
```

On Form1, I use delegate:

```
    public delegate void Tranferdata(string txt);
    public Tranferdata _tranfer;
    private void Gettxt(string txt)
    {
        tbx_Recieve.Text = txt;
    }
```

Form1 has a button to call Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Form2 will send value to Form1 after closed, Code on Form2:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    using (Form1 frm1 = (Form1)this.Owner)
    {
       frm1._tranfer(tbx_Numb.Text);
    }
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Close();
}
```

But my code doesn't work correctly. It crashed at 'using (Form1 frm1 = (Form1)this.Owner)' and show the System.InvalidCastException.
How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return a value from a Form in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-form-in-c)

Comment: Don't put it in a `using` statement when you cast like that, otherwise you're going to dispose the `Form1` instance that was passed into the closed method. Only use `using` when you want to destroy the object when you are done with it. There are other reasons why it won't work (`sender` is a Form2, not Form1) though and you are using a sledgehammer to drive a picture nail with the delegates and transfer...

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but I don't want that way. I better to use Delegate @Melvin

Comment: Can you show me how?, @RonBeyer

Comment: @RonBeyer Can you show me how to correct this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem:
In the Form 2:

```
public void SetParent(Form1 frm)
{
    frm1 = frm;
}
```

and call it in Form 1 at event call form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.SetParent(this);
    frm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it crashed on that line is because you didn't set Form1 to be the owner of Form2.

To fix, first have Form1 as a class variable and not as a local variable:

```
Form1 form1;
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   form1 = new Form1() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TopLevel = false, Visible = true };
   xtraUserControl1.Controls.Add(form1);
}
```

Then you can use it to assign Form2's owner when you create it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Owner = form1;
    frm2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

And also, like Ron Beyer mentioned in his comment, consider removing the using statement, it will close Form1, it doesn't sound like that's what you want to do.

Now, while that approach will work, there are some questions that you should consider here:
Why did you choose to use the "Owner" property in the first place? Do you really need it? Having Form1 as the owner of Form2 means that Form2 will close when Form1 is closed. Since you use ShowDialog on Form2 it will block the user from closing Form1 while Form2 is showing so it seems unneeded. 
If the reason for using the Owner property is just for the sake of using the delegate than you could have just added a property to Form2 to be of type Form1, which would have given you type safety and superior code.

But there is even a better way: MainForm can register to the Closed event for Form2 and call the method on Form1. This will remove unneeded dependencies (Form2 and Form1 will not know about each other at all) making the code healthier.

Comment: I rewrite my code based on your suggestions, but I crashed again, at **frm1._tranfer(tbx_Numb.Text);**  (An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'). I think the problem is program defined parent form of Form2 is MainForm, not Form1, because Form1 is added to UC on MainForm

Comment: Either frm1 or tbx_Numb were not assigned. Put a breakpoint on that line, debug your application until you reach the breakpoint and check both values to see which one was not assigned. Then fix your code accordingly. If you still need help, publish your new code here and I'll try to help.

Comment: I don't know how to write my code in comment. My code is modified a little bit: not use "using (Form1 frm1 = (Form1)this.Owner)" but "Form1 frm1 = (Form1)this.Owner". Pls, I need helps

Comment: You should debug your code. Put a breakpoint (by right clicking on the line and selecting to add a breakpoint), then press F5 to debug it. Run your scenario until it reaches the breakpoint. Then hover your mouse on both frm1 and tbx_Numb to see which one is null.

Comment: I traced this code many times, and I also know frm1 is null. But I don't know how to fix in this case.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `frm2.Owner = form1;`, is form1 null there? If it isn't, step through with F10, and check if frm2.Owner now is not null. If frm1 is null on that line, then maybe your load function does not get called, put a breakpoint there to verify.