# How do I send data back to the parent form, such as a list or value, in Visual Basic?

Tags: forms, visual-studio

I have a form that I open to have the user select data from. Then I want to send that data back to the form that was spawned that data. Here is my code from the parent form:

```
Private Sub bttn_AW_SelectUnits_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bttn_AW_SelectUnits.Click
    'TODO: Capture output from next menu
    Dim changeUnits As New AuditWizardUnits
    changeUnits.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

I could have it spawn a new form, but I have multiple forms that I want to collect data from, so I don't want to lose the data that has been collected already. I tried to google this, but all I can find is how to send data, not receive it. I also couldn't find how to do this beyond a binary "OK" or "cancel."

Does know how to do this?

Comment: I've been looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-form-in-c as well as the function DialogResult, but I'm not sure how to pass more than a button press with DialogResult, and I can't seem to make the list public in Visual Basic for the link.

Answer (score 1):

The DialogResult portion simply allows you to determine if the User selected "OK" (or your equivalent of "OK"), or simply cancelled the dialog by clicking the "X" in the top right (in which case there might not be any valid "selections" in the dialog to retrieve).

If the User clicked "OK", then you can retrieve any desired values from the form reference that you already have.  Conceptually, we are "pulling" from the main form, not "sending" from the child form.  This is easier because the main form already has a reference to the child form (you used that reference to display the dialog!).

To do the opposite, and "send" from the dialog to the main, you'd have to pass a reference to the main form into the dialog form.  There are cases where you'd want to do this, such as if you needed something to change in main, in real-time and possibly multiple times, **before** the dialog is closed by the user.  Sometimes you need to only "pull", sometimes you need to "send", and sometimes you might need to do both.  You'll have to decide which approach is best for your situation.

Assuming you only need to pull **after** the dialog is dismissed by the user, check the returned DialogResult, then use that form reference to retrieve the values:

```
Private Sub bttn_AW_SelectUnits_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bttn_AW_SelectUnits.Click
    'TODO: Capture output from next menu
    Dim changeUnits As New AuditWizardUnits
    If changeUnits.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok Then
        ' Access something directly from a Control: 
        Dim value As String = changeUnits.TextBox1.Text

        ' ...or use a property that YOU created in changeUnits:
        Dim values As List(Of String) = changeUnits.SelectedValues
    End If
End Sub
```

In the dialog, you return "OK" when the user clicks on your OK/Save/Continue type button:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(...) Handles btnOK.Click
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok
End Sub
```

For the List aspect, you'd have to make that List accessible from outside the class so it can be retrieved like in my snippet above:

```
Public Class AuditWizardUnits

    Public SelectedValues As New List(Of String)

End Class
```

You'd either populate that list before setting DialogResult, or populate it as the user interacts with the dialog.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It looks like my options for Dialog Result are under Windows.Forms

Comment: Ok it's back to working. That was, in fact, easier than I thought.