# How do I retrieve a custom list from another form in a using block?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm calling Form2 in a using block from Form1 and getting some data from text fields there and putting that into a custom list. What I would like to do is take that data, put it into my list and send it back to Form1. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do that, and my searches don't seem to be yielding quite what I'm looking for.

What I mean is from Form1:

```
using(Form2 form2 = new Form2()){
form2.showDialog();
}
```

And lets say I have the list:

```
List<customList> myList = new List<customList>;
```

What might be the best way to pass the List I'm getting in Form2 back to Form1?

Comment: You can either pass an object into Form2 constructor from Form 1 and set the values on that, or you can publish events from Form2 which Form1 subscribes to.

Comment: Or just add public propties to Form2 and get it after close dialog

Comment: I would recommend you to check on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5233526/5785572).

Comment: yes @EtienneFaucher I believe this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!