# Get a value from another Form c#

Tags: c#

**I am trying to get a value from another form in a text box**. When I click on a text box, another form appears that is a numeric keypad and I can enter a number.

**What I want is for the textbox I click to get the value of that new form**.

How could I do this?

*Example*:

**I have the next textbox**:

[image: First TextBox]

When I do click on this textbox appears the following form to introduce some numbers:

[image: Second Textbox]

**When I click on the enter button of the second form, I would like to close this form and get the value "78552" into the first textbox.**

I am trying putting the textbox of the second form as a public static but is not working.

What could I do?

EDIt:

This is what I am trying:

```
private void micrasmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tecladojm t = new Tecladojm();
        t.Show();

        using (var form = new Tecladojm())
        {
            //var result = form.ShowDialog();
            if (Tecladojm.buttonEnterClicked == true)
            {
                string val = form.DevolverNumeroMarcado();            
                micrasmin.Text = val;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/834980/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-form-in-windows-form/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a value from a Form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-form-in-c)

Comment: Don't show your interface. Show your code. Also specify if it's WPF or Winforms.

Comment: @maxspan but how could I do returning the value from a textbox?

Comment: Please follow the link it's taking input from text box and showing in other form

Comment: @PalleDue Judging from the second screenshot of the UI it is obviously winforms.

Comment: @maxspan Thanks for your help, I've updated the post with what I am trying but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, however I *usually* do the following.

1) Update your constructor in Form2 to include a parameter as so:

```
public Form2(string form1Text1, string form1Text2, string form1Text3)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.label1.Text = form1Text;
}
```

2) In your button click that opens the second form, simply do the following:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var form2 = new Form2(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text, this.textBox3.Text);
     form2.Show();
 }
```

That should work for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have to do this for three diferentes textbox, so if I do this I would lose the data of the first textbox if I try this in the second one, right?

Comment: @greatWallace It's my pleasure to help! :) Not at all... if you need to do this for three textboxes, then you would simply add more parameters to your Form2 constructor... i.e. public Form2(string form1Text, string form1Text2, string form1Text3) and of course update Form 1 to suit.I updated my question to give you a better example of that.